# jq: Get dimensions of 2d array

Tags: json, matrix, multidimensional-array, jq, dimensions

I'd like to retrieve the dimensions of a 2D array with `jq`.

test.json:

```json
{
  "data": [
    [1,2,3,4],
    [5,6,7,8]
  ]
}
```

I can get the major dimension:

```sh
$ jq < test.json '.data | length'
2
```

I can get the minor dimension:

```sh
$ jq < test.json '.data[0] | length'
4
```

I would like to get both at once, ie: (does not work, expected output)

```
$ jq < test.json '.data | [length, .[0] ???? ]'
[
  2,
  4
]
```

Is there any way to produce this expected output with jq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe each separate dimension into `length`:

```
$ echo '{
  "data": [
    [1,2,3,4],
    [5,6,7,8]
  ]
}' | jq '.data | [length, (.[0] | length)]'
[
  2,
  4
]
```

The filter could also be written as

```
.data | [., .[0]] | map(length)
```

Comment: without the parens, the expression would have been equivalent to `.data | [ (length, .[0] ) | length]`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a general solution for a strictly regular, n-dimensional array:

```
.data | [recurse( .[0]? | select(type=="array")) |  length]
```

For more about the concept of strict regularity, see below.

### As a function

With

```
def rho: [recurse( .[0]? | select(type=="array")) |  length];
```

`[ [[1,1],[2,2]], [[1,1],[2,2]], [[1,1],[2,2]]] | rho`

would yield: [3,2,2]

### Strict regularity

For present purposes, let's say a "matrix" is strictly regular if none of its entries is an array, and that
an n-dimensional JSON array is strictly regular if and only if the corresponding n-dimensional matrix is strictly regular.

To check that a JSON array is strictly regular in this sense, we can define `is_strictly_regular` (using the above definition of `rho`) as follows:

```
# Check whether the input has precisely the specified
# dimensions, and no additional arrays.
# It is assumed that $dimensions is an array of non-negative integers.
# If $dimensions is [], then return type!="array".
def strictcheck($dimensions):
  if type == "array"
  then ($dimensions|length) > 0
       and length == $dimensions[0]
       and all(.[]; strictcheck($dimensions[1:]))
  else $dimensions == []
  end;

def is_strictly_regular:
  rho as $d
  | strictcheck($d);
```